# Optional function in Swift with return type

Tags: swift

I do have a function with an optional return type. I am confused by its produced output. The code goes like this.

```
func displayAge(age: Int) -> Int? {
    return 23
}

if var age = displayAge(age: 22) {
    print("Age is correct")
} else {
    print("Age is incorrect")
}
```

I passed the age as 22 and I should get a output as Age is incorrect but I am getting Age is correct

Comment: `displayAge` returns a non-optional `23` no matter what number you pass. Can you explain why you think it is the incorrect age so that we can know exactly where you are confused?

Comment: @Sweeper if we pass age as 23 then according to simple if condition, it will execute the second print statement. I am confused why id statement condition is not working.

Comment: Can you explain what you’re trying to actually do? Don’t explain what your code is trying to do. Explain what you are trying to achieve. Like, why `age`? Why 22? What are you trying to display? What does the age belong to? Etc...

Comment: What do you think the line `if var age = displayAge(age: 22)` is doing? Can you explain what you think that line is doing?

Comment: I believe this is what you want to do: `func displayAge(age: Int) -> Bool { return age == 23 }; if displayAge(age: 22) {...}`

Comment: @Fogmeister I want to check whether the condition is true or not when I pass the value as 22. And also I am confused with ? sign. What if we want to return nill in our output?

Comment: @Carpsen90 This line will pass the vlaue 22 and assigns to varaible age. I think so. Please correct me.

Comment: Your example is completely pointless. The parameter is not used and a non-optional constant is returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be confused about this optional binding if statement:

```
if var age = displayAge(age: 22) {
    print("Age is correct")
} else {
    print("Age is incorrect")
}
```

This does the following:

- Call `displayAge(age: 22)`, check its return value
- If the return value is not `nil`

  - assign the return value to the variable `age`
  - `print("Age is correct")`
- Otherwise

  - `print("Age is incorrect")`

It does not check if `22` is equal to `23`. It will always print `Age is correct` because `displayAge` always returns `Optional(23)`, which is not `nil`.

You can check whether 22 is equal to 23 like this:

```
func displayAge() -> Int { return 23 }

if 22 == displayAge {
    print("Age is correct")
} else {
    print("Age is incorrect")
}
```

Or if you really want to use optional binding,

```
func displayAge(age: Int) -> Int? { return 23 == age ? 23 : nil }

if let _ = displayAge(age: 22) {
    print("Age is correct")
} else {
    print("Age is incorrect")
}
```

Comment: @Sweeper got it now.

Answer (score 0):

I think its easier of you make it in to a return bool like @Carpsen90 said in the comment.

```
func displayAge(age: Int) -> Bool {

}
```

In the function you could check if it's true or not this way :

```
// check if age is 23
if age == 23 {
    // then return true
    return true
} else {
    // otherwise return false
    return false
}
```

But to make that function smaller you code write something like this, and it will return a boolean value that's true or false.

```
// and for the code above you only need to write
return age == 23
```

To call the function and see if your age is correct or not and get prints or what ever code you want to be in the function.

```
if displayAge(age: 22) {
    // it's correct
    print("Age is correct")
} else {
    // otherwise incorrect
    print("Age is incorrect")
}
```

And if you want to make that even easier you could make some thing like this :

```
displayAge(age: 22) ? print("Age is correct") : print("Age is incorrect")
```